# Semaphore with OS process in Java

Tags: java, process, semaphore

I am executing a program using Java's ProcessBuilder so as to run it as a OS program.

The request is being pushed to a queue from where a consumer will consume and run it. Inside the consumer, I have used semaphore(8) and executor service to submit the request as thread.

Below is the corresponding code.

```
ProcessBuilder bldr = new ProcessBuilder().command(commandArray);
bldr.redirectErrorStream(true);
process = bldr.start();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String ch;
while ((ch = br.readLine()) != null) {
    output = output + ch;
}
br.close();
result = process.waitFor();
....
private static Semaphore semaphore;
private static ExecutorService threadExecutor;
....
semaphore = new Semaphore(8, true);
threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
....
ExecutorWorkerThread thread = new ExecutorWorkerThread(request);
threadExecutor.submit(thread);
semaphore.acquire();
```

Now the problem is irrespective of this Semaphore(8), the processes are getting executed one-after-another, Not in parallel.

Am I expecting the correct behavior and doing the correct thing? Kindly correct me. Let me know if any additional details are required.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? I think you don't need to use a semaphore but maybe a callable and future? But that is just a guess as I cannot tell what are you trying to do. max 8 threads run at once?

Comment: Updated the code. The ExecutorWorkerThread actually implements Callable. The requests are coming in and are put in a queue. From there, those are picked up and processed. All I want is to run 8 processes in parallel. but these threads are executed one after the other.